# Type of Eclipse project for sample Spring project

Tags: eclipse, spring, model-view-controller, project

In a tutorial at http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html Spring guys didn't say which Eclipse project they choose to create this sample application. Project icon has S symbol over it, so this isn't a Java project (marked with J symbol). 
However, it doesn't look like a Dynamic Web project either.

Could you please explain that S symbol and say which project type is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using the [Spring Eclipse plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-ide) (either that, or they are using the [Springsource Tool Suite IDE](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts), based on Eclipse)

With this plugin, a dynamic web project should get you the 'S' you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The S just means that the Spring nature is active (and it's either Spring IDE or SpringSource Tool Suite). In Eclipse-speak, I guess you should generate a dynamic web project, but it would be better to generate a Maven Project and import that into Eclipse (then Eclipse will automatically set the correct project type).